# LSTM regression model flat prediction

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, lstm

This is a time series regression problem for the battery capacity as output and a single input variable  as voltage; the relation is non-linear.
LSTM Model prediction of the test data always returns a semi-flat line, probably the mean of the output variable in the training data.

This is an example of predicted vs test set output values, with the following model parameters:
(Window size: 10, batch site: 256, LSTM nodes: 16)

[Prediction of the test data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNvXN.png)

Data had been normalized, down-sampled to 1 sec and later to 3 sec, original sampling was 10 Hz.
I was suspecting the voltage fluctuation is the problem, but sampling at 3 seconds hadn't resulted into noticeable improvement.

Here are the data after being down-sampled to 3 seconds:

[Normalized Training Data ; Y:SOC, X: Voltage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNPSw.png)

[Normalized Test Data ; Y:SOC, X: Voltage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuhlP.png)

I've tried many changes in the model and learning parameters as follows, but still the behavior is the same.
That's why i think it's not a parameter tuning issue, rather the model is not learning at all.

```
LSTM layer: always single, followed by Dense with no options.
LSTM nodes: [4,8,16,32]
Epoch:  : [16,32,64,128]
window size (input vector depth): [8,32,64,128]
Batch size: [32,64,128,256]
learning rate: [.0005,.0001,.001]
optimizer : ADAM, options:[ none, clipnorm=1, clipvalue=0.5]
```

Model specification Code:

```
    backend.clear_session()
    model1 = Sequential()
    model1.add(LSTM(16,input_shape=(win_sz, features_cnt) )) # stateless
    model1.add(layers.Dense(1))
    model1.summary()
```

Model training and validation Code:

```
n_epochs = 12
iterations = tr_samples_sh_cnt // batch_sz_tr
loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()
optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001)
loss_history = []

@tf.function
def train_model_on_batch():
    start = epoch * batch_sz_tr
    X_batch = df_feat_tr_3D[start:start+batch_sz_tr, :, :]
    y_batch = df_SOC_tr_2D[start:start+batch_sz_tr, :]

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        current_loss = loss(model1(X_batch), y_batch)
    gradients = tape.gradient(current_loss, model1.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model1.trainable_variables))
    return current_loss

for epoch in range(n_epochs+1):
    for iteration in range(iterations):
        current_loss = train_model_on_batch()
    if epoch % 1 == 0:
        loss_history.append(current_loss.numpy())
        print("{}.   \t\tLoss: {}".format(
            epoch, loss_history[-1]))
print('\nTraining complete.')


P_test = model1.predict(df_feat_test_3D)
```

After adding sigmoid activation function in both LSTM and Dense layers, a very small change observed, but far from reasonable fit.

[Prediction of the test data after adding activation function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3ovY.png)

Comment: Your model has no activation functions, so its completely linear.

Comment: which do you suggest for such timeseries problem (Relu, softmax, sigmoid , ... ). I recall Relu was suggeseted in an article by Brownlee for timeseries problems. But  when i've tried it at Dense layer, can't remember huge difference.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've added sigmoid to both LSTM and Dense, but still results not reasonable; the post edited with the new graph.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the activation function as @Dr. Snoopy  recommended